# ListView InsertItemTemplate in WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf, listview

Is there in WPF ListView something like InsertItemTemplate for ListView in ASP.NET?

Comment: i want to add control below listview(with 3 columns) which has textoboxes to write values to. After clicking add buttton values from these thextboxes goes to listview.
I have a problem with displaing this control. When I change width of the window then width of listview is changing and width of each column is changing also but width of control below listview does not change...
How can I manage this control to have width property in each column just like width in corresponding column of listview?

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm not quite sure what you are after, but you could provide normal form controls to add an additional item to the list (i.e. outside the markup of the ListView), or use a third party grid which provides in place editing such as the Telerik [RadGridView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx) or the Infragistics [XamDataGrid](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/xamdatagrid.aspx).

You could also swap out the CellTemplate based on the currently selected ListViewItem as described [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-3-in-place-edit).